# jQuery.css('width') with a floating point or decimal value

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser

I've set the width of a div to 330px by inspecting it with Chrome and then setting  the width manually. When I read the width back with `jQuery.css('width')` it comes back as 329.77777767181396px.

Does anyone know why this is defaulting to floating point, or whatever it is, instead of an integer?

Thanks

Comment: I am not completely answering your question but you can use `Math.round()`, it works perfectly

Comment: Yes.  I'm just wondering what got flipped, because it didn't used to do this.

Comment: you can refer to the W3c article on the answer i posted

Answer (score 3):

you can refer to the w3c specification below if you are really curious about this

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units

the floating values are rounded when the page is rendered, **the exact values are stored in the memory and used for its child element calculations**. For example, if your div is 105.4999px it is rendered to 105px, it's child elements with a width of 50% will be calculated as .5*100.4999 instead of .5*100.

to complete the whole information about this they are called as **subpixel** and you can have further reading with John Resig's(jQuery creator) article about the problems with subpixels

http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: Thanks for that. Where it gets me in trouble is when I try to save the value away in the user's DB record in a varchar 10 field, so that the next time they log in it's the default.   It's just puzzling what changed to break this suddenly.

Comment: well its really safe to round off the values as the w3c specs said

Comment: Yes.  It's not very clean here, though, because these .css() values come back as a string with 'px' on the end. So for each one (about 25) I have to strip off the 'px', get the raw number to an integer, do the Math.round, and then convert it back to a string with 'px' on the end. I'll do it.  I was just hoping to find out what changed and change it back.  I guess I could also increase the DB field length to accept all the digits.

Comment: I just looked at an older saved version of the code and the .css('width') returns and integer number: "330px".

Comment: This may be a clue:  when I read boxShadow the values from .css(boxShadow) are rgb(68,68,68) 2px 2.9999...px, 5.9999...px 0px.  
It got x_off exact (2), but not y_off (2.99…)  or blur_dist (5.99…), and then it got spread_dist (0) exact.
It seems that the values themselves are sometimes "on grid" (2.00000..), in which case the floating point comes back as 2,  and sometimes they're off  a hair. What in the world could cause that???

Comment: that's another topic please post another question for including what browser you tested it

Comment: Got it!  The long numbers were coming out because the (Chrome) browser zoom was set to 90%.