# Not able to get exact style attribute by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the Style attribute of a Div in jQuery, but the problem is it is not returning the decimal value.

For example:

if the style attribute is set as:

```
<div class="test" style="width:204.43px">
```

and when I try to retrieve the value in jQuery as:

```
var x = $('.test').css('width');
```

The output is:

```
204px
```

But it should return `204.43px`

Comment: It's working fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/bjwfcLmy/4/)**, It seems this issue is browser specific, which browser are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.css('width') with a floating point or decimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560401/jquery-csswidth-with-a-floating-point-or-decimal-value)

Comment: I tested it out jquery version below 3 doesn't take decimals. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bjwfcLmy/9/). and version 3 and above takes decimals [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bjwfcLmy/10/)

Comment: @locateganesh Now this makes sense, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned your code is not working in jquery version below 3. In this case, you can go with the pure JavaScript solution instead of jquery like below.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('test').style.width;
alert(x);
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:204.43px"></div>
```

In the above snippet I have used `id`. If you want to achieve it through class then you can get it like below.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.width;
alert(x);
```

```html
<div class="test" style="width:204.43px"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

i don't think decimal values are considered if you give in pixels. '40.8' px will be truncated to 40. decimals are considered only if you give in percentages.

Comment: Most browsers truncated the value but that was out of a practicality reason rather than because of following a standard that said "drop the fraction part". The [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units) clearly says that floating points are valid, also modern browsers round a float correctly nowadays.